# Как определить, откуда сайт подгружает данные?

Tags: python, парсер

Мне нужно спарсить данные о свободных номерах с сайта отелей (например, на эту дату [https://www.danhotels.com/Booking/SearchResults?fr=hp&com=box&ttl=ChooseYourRoom&SelectedHotelID=10119&ListHotelIds=10119&CheckIn=16.03.2023&CheckOut=23.03.2023&Pax[0].Adults=2&Pax[0].Children=0&Pax[0].Infants=0&site=dan](https://www.danhotels.com/Booking/SearchResults?fr=hp&com=box&ttl=ChooseYourRoom&SelectedHotelID=10119&ListHotelIds=10119&CheckIn=16.03.2023&CheckOut=23.03.2023&Pax%5B0%5D.Adults=2&Pax%5B0%5D.Children=0&Pax%5B0%5D.Infants=0&site=dan)), но при get запросе поле, где хранятся номера, пустое. Как определить, где откуда подгружаются эти данные, и как их достать? Это очень просто делается просто прокруткой через selenium, но мне поставили задачу его не использовать, и я не знаю, что делать

Comment: Через Fiddler посмотреть какие запросы ещё идут

Comment: Присмотритесь к этому запросу, https://api.danhotels.com/graphql, возможно это то, что вам нужно.